# Non-metro app for Windows Store?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'd like to develop an application for the Windows Store using Visual Studio 2012 and C#.
However when I create an empty project (XAML) having "Windows Store" selected I get a metro-app. I want an ordinary XAML-application because my application works only as a windowed application (the user wouldn't benefit from the Metro-interface at all).

So how can I create a default XAML-application without Metro but still be able to put it in the Windows Store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just build the desktop application like you normally would.  Don't pick Windows Store app or you'll end up with a metro app build on WinRT.

You'll need to run the certification kit against your application and submit it to MS.  You'll also still need a company account to submit to the store.

You can find more information here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/06/08/listing-your-desktop-app-in-the-store.aspx

Comment: be aware to that Microsoft doesn't handle installation or distribution of your app.  You get some visibility since it will be listed in the store, but distribution, collecting payment, etc. is all on you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to provide your own `Style` Templates for the controls you wish to use. The same way you would have done for any WPF/SL projects if you didn't want to use the standard out-of-the-box themes. So say for instance you want to use a `Button` but you don't want it to look like one of the default Light/Dark theme Buttons. Plop one on your design area, right click and go to Edit Template -> Edit a Copy and use Blend to style it however you want it to look. Unfortunately, this means you'll have to *Theme* all your controls to create your Theme where everything works together.

Which is one cool thing about how these environments are setup, you can just about literally make anything look however your imagination wants it to look. There's plenty of tutorials on the web on how to use Blend to customize Control Style Templates. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this but is there a way to make a windowed Metro-application?

Comment: @Hedge Not sure what you mean by that, although judging by the other answer and its upvotes I must have misunderstood the question. I was thinking more of an aesthetic sense way of changing it to not look like the metro interface.

Comment: there isn't a way to create a windowed Metro App. Metro apps are fullscreen / filled / snapped